# Mysql query to select Distinct Records on conditions?

Tags: mysql, select, distinct, distinct-values

i have table structure like this.. `ext_no` , `value` .. i want to select distinct records on condition..like when count of `ext_no` is **more than two** and *IF AND ONLY IF* all that `ext_no` `value` is zero..
I Want Expected Result Given below...like.. how to write mysql query this this..? any help would be appreciated.. Thanks in advance..

**Table Structure:**

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `ext_no` int(5) default NULL,
  `value` int(3) default NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `test`
--

INSERT INTO `test` (`ext_no`, `value`) VALUES
(12133, 0),
(12133, 0),
(12133, 0),
(22222, 0),
(44226, 0),
(44226, 0),
(44226, 1),
(44226, 2),
(99902, 1),
(99902, 2),
(99902, 3),
(11505, 0),
(11505, 0),
(11505, 0),
(11505, 0);
```

**Expected Result:**

```
ext_no  value
12133     0
11505     0
```

**Edit: i Tried-**

```
select distinct ext_no, value from test where value ='0' order by ext_no DESC;
```

Comment: What have you tried???  SO is not a free coding service site.  You post your query.  If it doesn't work, we can try to help you.

Comment: @Eric  yes i tried..i have edited my question..

Comment: @Eric how to modify this answer.. if i want to select all that records having value zero.. i mean not distinct or group by..i want to select all records..that having value zero only...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`count` skips `null` values. So you can `count` a `case` expression where the value is `0`, and then use a `having` condition to check that this count is equal to the total count:

```
SELECT   ext_no, MAX(value)
FROM     test
GROUP BY ext_no
HAVING   COUNT(*) > 2 AND 
         COUNT(*) = COUNT(CASE value WHEN 0 THEN 1 END)
```

Comment: thank you for your answer sir.. now i want to select all records.. i mean.. not distinct or group by..i want to select all that records having value 0 .. so that i can update or delete that records..how to modify this answer.. i tried using order by.. but it shows error..

Comment: @user10146017 if you have a new set of requirements, please post them as a new question

Comment: sure.. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53370339/mysql-query-to-delete-records-after-select) it is

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one, using **group by** and the **having** clause:

```
SELECT
    ext_no,
    SUM(value) as value
FROM
    test
GROUP BY
    ext_no
HAVING
    count(*) > 2 AND SUM(value) = 0
```

Comment: This will return `ext_no`s that have zeros and omit the rows that have different values. The OP asked for "IF AND ONLY IF all that ext_no value is zero"

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT t.ext_no, COUNT(*)
FROM test t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM test
    WHERE ext_no = t.ext_no AND ext_no > 0
)
GROUP BY t.ext_no
HAVING COUNT(*) > 2
```