# Mysql query to Delete records after select..?

Tags: mysql, select, sql-delete

after selecting records i want to delete that records..i tried following query - (after removing `,MAX(value)`  but its showing-    You can't specify target table 'test' for update in FROM clause

```
DELETE FROM test WHERE ext_no IN 
(
SELECT   ext_no, MAX(value)
FROM     test
GROUP BY ext_no
HAVING   COUNT(*) > 2 AND 
         COUNT(*) = COUNT(CASE value WHEN 0 THEN 1 END)
);
```

Comment: I don't get the logic - you appear to want to delete all ext_nos where there are more than 2 records for that ext_no AND ALL records for that ext_no have a value of 0. These 2 conditions seem incompatible can you add sample data and expected outcome as text to the question please.

Comment: @P.Salmon yes sure..  you can refer my previous question.. for  sample data [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52840268/mysql-query-to-select-distinct-records-on-conditions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below  - you need to use subquery for inner select statement

```
DELETE FROM test WHERE ext_no IN 
(
select ext_no from
(
SELECT   ext_no, MAX(value)
FROM     test
GROUP BY ext_no
HAVING   COUNT(*) > 2 AND 
         COUNT(*) = COUNT(CASE value WHEN 0 THEN 1 END)
)t)
```